# How to get what codec am I using in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc, codec

How to get information about what codec am I using in WebRTC? And how to change it to another.

With default settings I get bad quality audio, like it is from a speaker.

Answer (score 5):

the getStats API provides that information. See [this sample](https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/peerconnection/constraints/)
or alternatively chrome's chrome://webrtc-internals page.

[apprtc](https://apprtc.appspot.com/) has an information window that shows the codec used when you press 'i' while in a call.

The default is opus which should give you 'hd quality'

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately those Chrome stats are non-standard, and Firefox doesn't return the codec info in `getStats` [yet](https://bugzil.la/1225722).

Answer (score 2):

To change the codec you actually need to tamper with SDP. I also needed the same and to make my life easier I even wrote a [SDP parser](https://github.com/beradrian/sdpparser).